# Change Live-CD Plymouth Theme

Tags: boot, themes, live-cd, plymouth

I have tried editing adding a new plymouth to /usr/share/plymouth/themes, and using update-alternatives followed by update-initramfs.

I have tried editing the original ubuntu-logo and ubuntu-text plymouth themes. Nothing happens.

I have tried extracting initrd.lz, adding the plymouth theme AND editing the original ubuntu themes. Nothing. (I cannot use update-alternatives for the new initrd.lz, because it says /bin/bash does not exist when I try to chroot it).

Does anyone out there have a solution? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... looks like the default.plymouth link is a link that links to another location that links to itself. It's kind of confusing. But basically you just have to edit the ubuntu-text.plymouth file and the actual default.plymouth link as well. This is in initrd.lz.